# GitHub pages not sighting index.html within my dist. folder

Tags: github, frontend, github-pages

So I'm relatively new to frontend development (4 months in) and so far anytime I publish a project to GitHub, my index.html is always directly within the root folder.
But I started using bundlers (which are amazing by the way ) and that makes all my web files (including index.html) be within the dist. folder and not the root folder.
I have no problems with this when using live server but publishing to GitHub gives me a 404 error. Please how can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages can only serve files from the root or an `docs` folder. See the [GitHub Pages documentation on file sources](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites).

Bundlers generally allow you to specify the name of the outDir or you can add a rename step yourself.